# Switch connection string based upon culture when using NInject

Tags: binding, ninject, connection-string, currentculture

Please can anyone advise if it is possible to switch connection strings for a DbContext using Ninject binding, based upon Current Culture? My current (non-working) cod is as below.

```
    private static IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        try
        {
            kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
            kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

            RegisterServices(kernel);
            return kernel;
        }
        catch
        {
            kernel.Dispose();
            throw;
        }
    }

    private static string GetCultureBasedConnectionString()
    {
        string culture = "de-DE"; // TODO Replce with Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name
        string cultureBasedConnectionString = ConnectionStringHelper.GetConnectionStringWithCulture(culture);
        return cultureBasedConnectionString;
    }

    private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        kernel.Bind<ApplicationDb>().To<ApplicationDb>()
            .InRequestScope()
            .WithConstructorArgument("connectionString", context => GetCultureBasedConnectionString());
        .
        .
        .
    }
```

This is based upon the example here, [Ninject - dynamically specifying a connection string based on a sub domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7024952/ninject-dynamically-specifying-a-connection-string-based-on-a-sub-domain), but it does not call through to my `GetCultureBasedConnectionString()` method on each request except when the application starts up...

I have read here on So that using NInjects Rebind() method is not good.

[This SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31624116/how-to-bind-classes-with-required-connection-string-in-constructor-using-ninject) also did not get me in the right direction, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are describing the expected behavior. The binding code is executed when.. well when you call `Bind` - and not every time the type is retrieved. The Func/Method specified in `ToMethod` would be executed every time the binding is applied.

Although i believe you can simplify your code to:

```
kernel.Bind<ApplicationDb>().To<ApplicationDb>()
        .InRequestScope()
        .WithConstructorArgument(
            "connectionStringGetter",
            context => GetCultureBasedConnectionString());
```

and thus get rid of `ConnectionStringGetter()`.

Answer (score 0):

A slight change to use a `Func<string>` which calls back to my `GetCultureBasedConnectionString()` method and this seems to defer execution of the `GetCultureBasedConnectionString()` method until the HttpRequest is made, which now appears to be working for me... Is that anticipated behviour?

```
    private static IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        try
        {
            kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
            kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

            RegisterServices(kernel);
            return kernel;
        }
        catch
        {
            kernel.Dispose();
            throw;
        }
    }

    private static string GetCultureBasedConnectionString()
    {
        string culture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name;
        string cultureBasedConnectionString = ConnectionStringHelper.GetConnectionStringWithCulture(culture);
        return cultureBasedConnectionString;
    }

    private static Func<string> ConnectionStringGetter()
    {
        var function = new Func<string>(GetCultureBasedConnectionString); 
        return function;
    }

    private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        kernel.Bind<ApplicationDb>().To<ApplicationDb>()
            .InRequestScope()
            .WithConstructorArgument("connectionStringGetter", context => ConnectionStringGetter());
```